# nodejs, mongodb and handlebarjs with async-await CRUD operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, handlebars.js, crud

Project on **Get-Post-Update-Delete requests** using the **mongoDB mongoose and Express-handlebars**. My code **works fine for get and post request**, but it's giving e**rror for my update and delete request.** So, I am requesting for codes from your side on how to do **update and delete operation works with async function and hbs.**

Comment: Hello. To improve your question, please give more information about what you already 
tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For update you can use the PATCH like so

```
router.patch('/users/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const updates = Object.keys(req.body)
    const allowedUpdates = ['name', 'email','password','age']
    const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update))
    if(!isValidOperation){
        return res.status(404).send({ error: "Invalid update field" })
    }

    try{
        const _id = req.params.id

        const updateUser = await User.findById(_id)

        updates.forEach((update) => updateUser[update] = req.body[update]);

        await updateUser.save()

        if(!updateUser){
            return res.status(404).send()
        }

        //render your hbs file here

    }catch(e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

For the DELETE

```
router.delete('/users/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try{
       
        const userDelete = await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)

        if (!userDelete) {
            return res.status(404).send("Error")
        }

        //then you render your HBS file here 
         res.render()
    }catch(e) {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }
})
```